I'm trying to make a DIY 10,000 lumen LED grow light and need some feedback
I’m trying to make a DIY grow light out of LEDs but I really wanna make sure it’s safe so that I can leave it on unattended.
I bought a 12v LED strip but unfortunately there doesn’t seem to be a data sheet for it available online. Each segment has 9 LEDs, 3 RGB 5050s, 3 clear white 2835s, and 3 warm white 2835s. I wanted to know how much current the LEDs draw so I hooked it up to a variable power supply to monitor the amperage of each line on a strip 12 segments long.
The red, green, and blue lines each drew about 165 mA and the two white lines drew 280 mA. Dividing that by 36 LEDs per line, it seems that each LED draws either 4.6mA or 7.8mA, depending on the type of LED.
I’m wanting to connect these lines to a 12v, 10A power supply and control them with Arduino PWM activating 5 MOSFET transistors. The light itself would have 16 strips wired in parallel that are each 8 segments long. In total this would make 128 segments and each color line would contain 384 LEDs.
The full brightness would have the two white lines energized %100, the red line energized %60, the blue line energized %30, and the green line energized %10. I think that would mean 768 white LEDs at 7.8mA each, 384 red LEDs at 2.76mA each, 384 blue LEDs at 1.38mA each, and 384 green LEDs at 0.46mA each. In total that should add up to a total of 7.58A at full power.
The current ended up being quite a bit higher than I anticipated going into this and I don’t really know anyone who has this kind of experience with electronics so I wanted to get feedback before proceeding. I still want to make a DIY solution so I can have full control over the lights to experiment with what type of light plants crave but I really want it to be safe.
Would a setup like this work if I had the LEDs mounted to a heat sink/fan? Would switching to 24v light strips allow me to get the same wattage/brightness at half the amperage so it’s safer? I’m a semiconductor tool technician and I’m doing this project to learn more so any input would be really appreciated

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There are actually three of each, the post is fixed now

You can buy off-the-shelf COB LED chips specifically tuned to the wavelenghts that plants need. That may be an easier option, unless you want to do this as a learning exercise. Just mentioning it in case you aren't aware.

Well this is primarily a learning exercise but that sounds like a great fallback option. And if I do go with my own set up I’m sure I could learn a lot from those chips either way. Thanks!


Would a setup like this work if I had the LEDs mounted to a heat sink/fan?

For all the detail not given, it should work.

Would switching to 24 V light strips allow me to get the same wattage/brightness at half the amperage so it’s safer?

Depends. I suggest makes no difference rather than Yes:
With an even number of stripes (you mention 16) all controlled the same, you can just put two 12 V stripes in series for 24 V operation.

there doesn’t seem to be a data sheet for it

reconsider your choice of supplier&product.
If the probability of catastrophic failure is greater with home-brew monitoring than without, you're safer without that monitoring.


Dividing [165/280 mA] by 36 LEDs per line, it seems that each LED draws either 4.6 mA or 7.8 mA

It may seem that way, but that's not the common way to build 12 V LED light sources:
Blue (& "white") LEDs need from 2.5 to 3.7 V, expect three in series.
Green would need 1.9 to 4.0 V, red 1.6 to 2 V, allowing more than 3 in series (never actually seen more than 3).
But then, I don't see how the current through individual LEDs is significant.


experiment with what type of light plants crave

Experimentation does not lead to less information.
It is plain to see what part of the spectrum plants don't harvest: green.

Thank you for all the feedback, are there specific details that I could give that would indicate potential issues?

Didn't think of anything beyond the ordinary (bad "links"/contacts/"connections" having significant resistance and getting hot, accordingly). At the currents mentioned, I don't see risks I don't expect you to be aware of. Depending on the size and isolation of "the grow volume", "de-heating" it may be an issue - as in operation at elevated temperatures reduces semiconductor life time significantly.
